# Is there a name for this feature of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

Working with Promises is convenient because `.then` accepts promises,  functions that do not return promises and functions that do return promises.

Is there a word for this technique of "wrapping" values into a consistent API?

Is this behavior related to the unit function of monads in category theory?

Comment: I'd say this is plain old polymorphism on argument types in action. `unit` aka `return` simply puts pure value in context. And if javascript was strongly typed you'd have to be explicit about types. For example `Just 10 >>= \x -> x + 1` wont typecheck in haskell. While `Just 10 >>= return . \x -> x + 1` does.

Comment: FYI, `.then()` only accepts functions as an argument.  They don't accept promises.    The functions can return either a promise or a value and the `.then()` handler will behave accordingly.

Comment: In both cases a function is passed, but with different type: (a -> b) or (a -> Promise). The former type is more general than the latter. So maybe `then` is polymorphic within the function type? Anyway, `then`'s return type is always a new, non-nested `Promise`.